# Does the auto-flagging algorithm need to be calibrated for Esperanto?

Tags: support, questions, flagging

The review queue for the low quality posts contained a question written in Esperanto, [Kiu el la esprimoj “abomeni” kaj “malami” estas la plej forta?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/kiu-el-la-esprimoj-abomeni-kaj-malami-estas-la-plej-forta) and [an answer](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/1408/64) for [How do you translate "Top 10 X" (in the title of an article or video)?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/how-do-you-translate-top-10-x-in-the-title-of-an-article-or-video) Both of them are fine, and there should not be any reason to automatically flag them. Compared with English, there are worse posts that should get an automatic flag for *low quality*.

Does the algorithm for auto-flagging low level posts need to be *calibrated* for Esperanto?
I guess that it flagged the question because the question was short, or because the number of words was lower than a specific limit. It doesn't seem to consider the difference between English and Esperanto.

I understand we have posts in English and Esperanto, but should not the auto-flagging algorithm be adjusted not to flag so easily posts written in Esperanto?

Comment: I imagine there is a way to adapt the auto-flagging mechanism to the language being used, since there is a Stack Exchange in Russian. If it uses the same parameters set for English, it would not work correctly for Russian, either being too picky, or being too permissive.